# HaProxy - Abillity to redirect subdomains and the base domain to the same backend

Tags: linux, domain, haproxy, subdomain

I need some help with the HaProxy setup.

Currently, I have the following config:

```
frontend fe_main_http
  bind :80
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
  use_backend %[req.hdr(Host),lower]

frontend fe_main_https
    bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/ no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    use_backend %[req.hdr(Host),lower]


backend test1.domain.com
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    server s1 1.2.3.4:80 check

...
```

This means, that any domain name will be redirected to the appropriately named backend. (For example: `example.com` to `backend example.com`)

The thing is - I want it to be set up for the subdomains of those domains as well.
Basically speaking, **any subdomain** of the base domain (e.g. `test.example.com` or `*.example.com`) **and the base domain itself** (e.g. `example.com`) **should point to the same backend** (e.g. `backend example.com`).

I've heard that it can be done with regex; however, I had no luck with setting this thing up. :(

Maybe someone has faced a similar thing and can help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a regex (and remember they are expensive) but you do need to specify the domain name.

Consider this:

```
        use_backend example.com if { req.hdr(host) -i example.com }
```

Now match for all subdomains with `-m end`:

```
        use_backend example.com if { req.hdr(host) -i -m end .example.com }
```

Comment: Yes, but the thing is - I want to use that with multiple domains, and creating more "use_backend" will clutter the config. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: @RodionGrinberg And creating more `backend`s won't clutter the config?

Comment: Well, it will; but not as much as additionally configuring frontend and backend side. I am adding the new backend using bash script, so, if possible, can the current config be modified?

Comment: Well then you can add `use_backend` by script too!